# How to parse LICENSE file? (Apache, Flora, BSD, ...)

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I want to get license name and version from LICENSE file.

Is there exist license file format for all the Flora, Apache, BSD, etc... ?

For example, the content would be

```
Flora License

Version 1.1, April, 2013

http://floralicense.org/license/

TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOR USE, REPRODUCTION, AND DISTRIBUTION

1. Definitions.

<...>

   Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]

   Licensed under the Flora License, Version 1.1 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://floralicense.org/license
```

Is it safe to read the name and version with below regex?

```py
r'.*Licensed under the (.*) License, Version (.*) \(the \"License\"\).*;'
```

Comment: What language is this? What kind of Regex?

Comment: Given the example regex, I've assumed this is python and modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do with a single regex, and it's very complicated to do in a fully functional language (with or without regexes).

There is no standard to how these are written; different licenses use different phrasing, so you won't be able to come up with an all-inclusive template with which to extract the items you're looking for.

To parse meaning out of English text, you'd essentially need [Natural Language Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) (NLP), which is probably 5-10 years away from being feasible to this kind of use.

Your best bet is probably to write regexes to match each license you know of and put them all in a giant and ugly if/then/else statement.  Many licenses look roughly comparable to the GNU GPL or else the BSD licenses, so you can hopefully get three or so good regexes for 90+% of the popular licenses out there, but there will always be outliers.

You might be able to cheat and get the outliers with a spell-check system: if it's not a dictionary word, perhaps it's the license name.

(I am not supplying an example implementation of that "best bet" because it's still too broad a question.  You'll need to curate a collection of licenses and then create a series of regexes that can extract the names from as many as possible per regex, figure out the order, and then put them in your if/then/else conditional.  If you want help doing that, you'll have to ask a question that offers the text of each of the licenses you want to parse as well as samples of the regexes you've tried.)